# Как добавлять ajax-обработчик в классе?

Tags: php, wordpress

Через функции `ajax` добавляется примерно так:

```
function ajax_handler(){

    echo 'ok';
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_handler', 'ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_handler', 'ajax_handler');
```

а как добавить этот код внутри класса?
т.е. к какому событию прикреплять, или в конструкторе прикрепить `ajax_handler` ?
Событие должно срабатывать в админке, кликнув по определённой кнопке.
Обработчик для кнопки сделал через `javascript`, а как теперь привязать `ajax_handler` к классу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У callback тип callable подробнее можно почитать тут https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php.

Пример с объектом:

```
$krya = new Krya();
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_handler', [ $krya, 'ajax_handler'] );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_handler', [ $krya, 'ajax_handler' ] );

class Krya {

   public function ajax_callback() {
       echo 'ok';
    exit;
   }

}
```

Пример со статическим методом:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_handler', [ 'Krya', 'ajax_handler'] );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_handler', [ 'Krya', 'ajax_handler' ] );

class Krya {

   public static function ajax_callback() {
       echo 'ok';
       exit;
   }

}
```

Comment: а как добавить `add_action` также в класс?

Comment: Можешь в __constuct() добавить. По личному опыту лучше использовать 1-й вариант с объектом.